# Get last result in interactive Python shell

Tags: python

In many symbolic math systems, such as Matlab or Mathematica, you can use a variable like `Ans` or `%` to retrieve the last computed value. Is there a similar facility in the Python shell?

Comment: Even in Python the last answer will be 42.

Comment: 42? Everyone missed the opportunity for a Prior Incantato reference!

Comment: [in]>>> _1   [out]>>> 42? Everyone missed the opportunity for a Prior Incantato reference!

Answer (score 315, accepted):

Underscore.

```
>>> 5+5
10
>>> _
10
>>> _ + 5
15
>>> _
15
```

Comment: It only works in the interactive shell, though.  Don't rely on it for scripts.

Comment: Additionally, it doesn't work if the variable `_` has been previously assigned. It's not uncommon, as this symbol is also used for throwaway variables (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python)

Comment: Yay, the final piece. With this I can use interactive python as my calculator.

Answer (score 106):

Just for the record, ipython takes this one step further and you can access every result with _ and its numeric value

```
In [1]: 10
Out[1]: 10

In [2]: 32
Out[2]: 32

In [3]: _
Out[3]: 32

In [4]: _1
Out[4]: 10

In [5]: _2
Out[5]: 32

In [6]: _1 + _2
Out[6]: 42

In [7]: _6
Out[7]: 42
```

And it is possible to edit ranges of lines with the %ed macro too:

```
In [1]: def foo():
   ...:     print "bar"
   ...:     
   ...:     

In [2]: foo()
bar

In [3]: %ed 1-2
```

Comment: Found `__` and `___` by chance as well in 1.2.1.

Answer (score 22):

IPython allows you to go beyond the single underscore `_` with double (`__`) and triple underscore (`___`), returning results of the second- and third-to-last commands.

Alternatively, you can also use `Out[n]`, where `n` is the number of the input that generated the output:

```
In [64]: 1+1
Out[64]: 2

...

In [155]: Out[64] + 3
Out[155]: 5
```

For more info, see https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.04-input-output-history.html .