# How to get the value of the last assigned variable in iPython?

Tags: python, ipython

I am a total iPython newbie, but I was wondering if there is a way to get the value of the last assigned variable:

```
In [1]: long_variable_name = 333
In [2]: <some command/shortcut that returns 333>
```

In R we have `.Last.value`:

```
> long_variable_name = 333
> .Last.value
[1] 333
```

Comment: You know you can do tab completion right?

Comment: yes, I'm just wondering if there is a command/shortcut

Comment: `<up_arrow>, <backspace 5 times>, <enter>`  ;-)

Answer (score 32):

There's a shortcut for the last *returned* object, `_`.

```
In [1]: 1 + 3
Out[1]: 4

In [2]: _
Out[2]: 4
```

Comment: I guess that might be a difference between R and Python: a variable assignment in R invisibly returns the value, while in Python this doesn't happen

Comment: Returned value asked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200020/get-last-answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use IPython's `In` and `Out` variables which contain the commands/statements entered and the the corresponding output (if any) of those statements.

So, a naive approach would be to use those variables as the basis of defining a `%last` magic method.

However, since not all statements necessarily generate output, `In` and `Out` are not synchronous.

So, the approach I came up with was to parse `In`, and look for the occurrences of `=` and parse those lines for the output:

```
def last_assignment_value(self, parameter_s=''):
     ops = set('()')
     has_assign = [i for i,inpt in enumerate(In) if '=' in inpt] #find all line indices that have `=`
     has_assign.sort(reverse=True) #reverse sort, because the most recent assign will be at the end
     for idx in has_assign:
         inpt_line_tokens = [token for token in In[idx].split(' ') if token.strip() != ''] #
         indices = [inpt_line_tokens.index(token) for token in inpt_line_tokens if '=' in token and not any((c in ops) for c in token)]
         #Since assignment is an operator that occurs in the middle of two terms
         #a valid assignment occurs at index 1 (the 2nd term)
         if 1 in indices:
             return ' '.join(inpt_line_tokens[2:]) #this simply returns on the first match with the above criteria
```

And, lastly to make that your own custom command in IPython:

```
get_ipython().define_magic('last', last_assignment_value)
```

And, now you can call:

```
%last
```

And **this will output the term assigned as a string** (*which may not be what you want*).

However, there is a caveat to this: in that if you had entered incorrect input that involved assignment; e.g.: `(a = 2)`, this method will pick it up. And, if your assignment involved variables: e.g. `a = name`, this method will return `name` and the **not the value** of name.

Given that limitation, you can then use the `parser` module to try and evaluate the expression like this (which can be appended to `last_assignment_value` in the last `if statement`):

```
import parser
def eval_expression(src):
    try:
        st = parser.expr(src)
        code = st.compile('obj.py')
        return eval(code)
    except SyntaxError:
        print 'Warning: there is a Syntax Error with the RHS of the last assignment! "%s"' % src
        return None
```

However, given the possible evils of `eval`, I've left that inclusion up to you.

But, to be perfectly honest, **a truly wholesome method would involve a parsing of the statement to verify the validity of the found input, as well as the input before it and more.**

REFERENCES:
https://gist.github.com/fperez/2396341