# Get result of line above

Tags: python

in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200020/get-last-result-in-interactive-python-shell)  it is explained, how to use the result of a previous code execution by using 
`_`, e.g.

```
>>> 5+5
10
>>> _
10
>>> _ + 5
15
>>> _
15
```

The question is inspired by languages like Mathematica, where you can easily call the result of the last line.

I notices, that this example does not work when you execute it all at ones, e.g.

```
5+5
_+5
```

Is there a corresponing way to calculate without defining new variables each time?

---

Edit: 
The role of `_` has been understood. The question is, wether there is (can be/ can't be)  a corresponding statement that reads the result of the last line within the same execution.

Comment: This is purely for quickly experimenting on the interactive CLI. In actual Python code you’d always use variables.

Comment: You maybe would use variables in Python, but is there no other way?

Comment: `_` will store the value of the last evaluated expression in the IDLE.  It has nothing to do with "lines" per se

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior of `_` is only available in REPL. `_` holds the output of that the last expression evaluated to. It should be noted, if the previous expression produced a TRACEBACK, `_` will hold the last valid output. You could also chain `_` upto three times (in IPython), to go fetch the 3rd last output:

```
>>> 5
5
>>> 6
6
>>> 7
7
>>> ___
5
>>> __
7
>>> _
7
```

If you use it in actual scripts, you can treat it `_` as a variable name (not recommended, if you plan to use the variable), for example:

```
_ = 10
print(_)

# will print 10
```

But the behavior you get at `REPL` can't be emulated in an actual script.