# Pycharm IDE, is there a ans-like matlab in console

Tags: python, matlab, pycharm, ide

I was wondering if in pycharm's debugger console there was something like the matlab ans variable, that always store the previous answer from the command window.

Comment: Try `_`. I rarely use the debugger, but it's an underscore in interactive consoles.

Comment: Thank you! that's it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get last result in interactive Python shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200020/get-last-result-in-interactive-python-shell)