# How to print out the result of the last statement of an arbitrary Python script (not in interactive shell)?

Tags: python

In an interactive Python shell, I can get the result of the last statement [by using an underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200020/get-last-result-in-interactive-python-shell):

```py
>>> x = 1
>>> y = 2
>>> x+y
3
>>> print(_)
3
```

How to make this code work outside of an interactive shell, like from a Python script?

For example, I have code.py :

```py
x = 1
y = 2
x+y
```

I want to run

```
python show_the_latest.py code.py
```

and get `3` as the output:

```bash
$ python show_the_latest.py code.py
3
```

Limitations:

- The script is given by a user. I don't know the last statement.
- Parsing the script is possible. But it should be a proper parsing with building an AST, not a hack.

Comment: `print(r)`, perhaps? It’s not clear why you’d need anything like this when running outside the Python REPL.

Comment: The code in your question doesn't work in an interactive shell either. Instead of `r = x + y`, you would need to enter simply `x + y`. The `_` trick only works when the previous line contained only an expression, not an assignment.

Comment: `_` contains the last thing that was printed by the REPL. But when you run a script, nothing is automatically printed, so there's no need for `_`. This is a convenience so you don't have to assign everything to a variable and print it by hand.

Comment: @esqew I need to simulate the same behavior as SQL script where the last statement is the result of the script that needs to be output.

Comment: Have you tried building the AST yourself? I think you'd just need to do up a `NodeTransformer` to wrap the last expression/statement with `print()`.

Comment: @wjandrea yes, not bash specific - I need Python code - `show_the_latest.py `. Added your line. Thank you!
Re AST - I was hopping there are some standard way of building it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete hack, but it works for your given example.  The downside is that its wrapping the last line of the code to be executed into a `print()` function, so if the target routine actually has a print statement last, you're going to get a `None` as output:

```
#show_the_latest.py
import sys
import subprocess

try:
    target = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    print("Target routine was not passed in")
    sys.exit()

with open(target) as program:
    code = [line.strip() for line in program.readlines() if line.strip() != ""]
    
if code:
    code[-1] = f"print({code[-1]})"
    to_execute = ["python", "-c", "; ".join(code)]
    subprocess.Popen(to_execute)
```

code.py

```
x = 1
y = 2
x+y
```

Then `python show_the_latest.py code.py` will output `3`

Note that this is definitely not completely robust, and there should probably be a more complete line validation check within the list comprehension that is building the code to be executed.  For example, in its current form, if any line contains a comment `#`, then nothing after that will be executed, because the `-c` modifier of the python executable will consider everything after the # to be part of the comment.  The check I did include will make sure that blank lines don't result in a syntax error.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I'm looking for a more robust solution. There are multiple cases when the last line does not actually reflects the last statements - comment, under `if`, function, etc.